# What schema structure to use for this app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, schema

I want to create an expense tracking app but don't know how to make my schema structure.

### The layout:

[image: page1][image: page2]

### The schema:

```
module.exports = {


  expenseList: [

      {
      uid: 'some-uid1',
      createdAt: 'some-date1',
      expenseItems: [
      {
        date: 'date11',
        desc: 'desc11',
        amount: 'amount11'
      },
      {
        date: 'date11',
        desc: 'desc11',
        amount: 'amount11'
      }]
      },


      {
      uid: 'some-uid',
      createdAt: 'some-date',
      expenseItems: [
      {
        date: 'date1',
        desc: 'desc1',
        amount: 'amount1'
      },
      {
        date: 'date1',
        desc: 'desc1',
        amount: 'amount1'
      },
      {
        date: 'date1',
        desc: 'desc1',
        amount: 'amount1'
      }]
    }

  ]


};
```

1. How do I change my schema so I can loop through expenses and display createdAt property as a clickable link that redirects to that expense items?
2. When do I use Arrays and when do I use Objects in my schema?
3. Where do I need uid (unique ids)?

I will use firebase for this app

Comment: Is your expense list always date based? From your second screen of expense details, it seems that you can have different dates.

Comment: I'm thinking about 2 different dates. One date for each expense item and another one date for expense itself when it is created with its items. When rendering expense list (not expense item list) I want to display when that expense was created. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an expenseList with a date and expenseItems associated with it. You can have a schema roughly like this. expenseList will be an array of objects. Each expenseList is an object containing uid (to uniquely identify the list), createdAt and array of expenseItems with its own set of properties.

```
expenseList: [{
    uid: 'some-uid',
    createdAt: 'some-date',
    expenseItems: [
    {
      date: 'date1',
      desc: 'desc1',
      amount: 'amount1'
    },
    {
      date: 'date1',
      desc: 'desc1',
      amount: 'amount1'
    }
    ]
}]
```

You can iterate over this expenseList to display createdAt in your first screen. On clicking of that, depending on the unique id of that expenseList, fetch the expenseList and display the expenseItems on the second screen.

I have not used firebase before, so you might have to tweak the schema a little.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I will give it a go!

Comment: Just updated my schema. Could you help me out with iteration here? how do I access createdAt property for both expenses?  Trying iterate through Object keys but no luck yet.

Comment: You just have to iterate through the expenseList array. And in each iteration, access the createdAt property. What object keys are you trying to iterate on?

Comment: Right! this worked for me: `const expenseDate = list.expenseList.map(item => item.createdAt)` . was messing around with it in `http://jsbin.com`.  `list` is my schema here.